# Cant find textbox on Chrome Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome

i'm want to use selenium to access this web https://vnsw.gov.vn/, and this process required login first and continue, but i'm get in stuck at the step find the input username and password , when i inspect this web the input username

```
id:"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ucLogin_CustomLogin_UserName"
```

but in when debug in code i can't find anything like that,i have tried to use find element by id, by name, but no way has effected :(. please help me!!! (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the element is inside an iframe. You have to switch to that iframe first
[image]